# Add TMS layer in Tilemill

Tags: web-mapping, tilemill, tile-map-service

Is it possible to add a TMS layer to TileMill to compose a map, if yes, how is it possible to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, TMS is not in the [list of layer types supported by Tilemill](http://mapbox.com/tilemill/docs/manual/adding-layers/#layer_types_supported_by_tilemill).

- CSV
- ESRI shapefile
- GeoJSON
- KML
- GeoTIFF
- SQLite
- PostGIS

A workaround is to use [tilemill-reference-layer](https://github.com/mapbox/tilemill-reference-layer). It's limited to maps hosted at MapBox though. Another option would be to download the tiles you're interested in and convert it to supported formats though that one could get very messy and troublesome.

Comment: Some advice to convert from TMS to one of the supported from TileMill?